# How to add focus to an HTML button when loading dynamically?

Tags: jquery, html, button, autofocus

I have some kind of tutorial with "Next" and "Previous" buttons that are loaded *dynamically*. They are loaded dynamically because the buttons have some kind of `data-attribute=""` that I need to retrieve and is updated to a different value depending on what step I am on.

**I want** the "Next" button to be "clicked" when the user presses **Enter**. When I first load the tutorial, the "Next" button has the `autofocus` attribute:

```
<button value='1' class='decrementer' 'type='button' >Prev</button>
<button value='1' class='incrementer' 'type='button' autofocus>Next</button>
```

This works fine, and I can press "Enter" to progress to the next step when I first load the buttons.

Each `NextStep()` or `PrevStep()` function then rewrites the buttons with updated attributes. The "Next" button again has `autofocus` written with it. However, it is not being focused and pressing **Enter** doesn't work to progress it this time.

```
//"NextStep()" function
$(document).on('click', ".incrementer", function () 
{
    var num = $(this).attr("value");
    var num = parseInt(num, 10);
    num = num + 1;
    $("#display").text(num);

    $("#button-container").html("<button value='" + num + "' class='decrementer' 'type='button' >Prev</button><button value='" + num + "' class='incrementer' 'type='button' autofocus>Next</button>");

});
```

I don't have this problem if I don't reload the buttons dynamically (I can hold enter and it will increment indefinitely).

**Problem:** How can I make this "Next" button retain focus when loaded dynamically so that I can progress using the *Enter* key?

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/L0dvtrcd/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use

```
$('#button-container .incrementer').focus();
```

...or...

```
$('#button-container .decrementer').focus();
```

...in the appropriate locations. See the updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L0dvtrcd/8/).

Answer (score 1):

Add the line

```
$("#button-container button.incrementer").focus();
```

or

```
$("#button-container button.decrementer").focus();
```

after you update the HTML.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L0dvtrcd/11/)

Alternatively, you may decide to not update the whole HTML at all. Just leave the buttons there, and only change their attributes.

Comment: Hmm... not sure why I didn't think of that lol. Way easier than rewriting everything. Oh well, thanks!